# Code length or tape size: brainf... (munged)

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, brainfuck

#### Is it best to have a longer tape size than program size with brainfuck? Or is it better the other way round?

**Also, how big relative to each other?**

I'm trying to make a brainfuck interpreter for an Arduino.  I know this has been done before, but I'm adding things such as  an [Adafruit Display](https://www.adafruit.com/products/716) and code-writing ability.

Because of this, the code is quite long, especially since I'm storing both code and tape in arrays:

```
char code[] = {};
byte tape[] = {};
```

> Memory should consist of at least 30000 cells, some existing brainfuck programs do need more so this should be configurable or unbounded.

I know I'm never going to fit 30000 cells into a Uno, but it seems like dynamic memory is the way to get the most space out of it.  Any way of doing this appreciated.

Currently, `char code[512] = {};` and `byte tape[1024] = {};` uses "1,807 bytes (88%) of dynamic memory", but that's just the interpreter sketch.  I'll need to squash some more code in there too.  The code is [here](https://github.com/MarcelloTheArcane/brainfork) for anyone who is interested.

Comment: [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is your friend.

Comment: seeing that you tagged this c++ also. why not a `vector` ? alternatively if you cannot use continuus memory for some reason a `deque`. it's slower though.

Comment: _uses 1,807 bytes (88%) of dynamic memory_.....not dynamic....

Comment: and your code, simply, does not exists... ;)

Comment: @LPs well there are branches with stuff. But yeah the link directly has no code currently

Comment: arduino (UNO) has only 2kb memory for variables

Comment: @LPs - regarding _uses 1,807 bytes (88%) of dynamic memory_, thats just what i got at compilation from the IDE.  I've branched to add code - once each bit works, i'll merge them with the master...

Comment: XY problem. An arduino has 16k **bits**. Those 30.000 cells are not going to fit, and that is not going to change regardless of the C++ you write.

Comment: @MSalters I know.  I asked what's the best proportions code/tape length for brainfuck.  And ways to get the most out of the available space (hence asking about dynamic memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it using a `map` object, instead of creating a limited array. Use the indexes as *keys* and the value in that cell as a *value* (delete it if it equal to zero, and create a new entry in the map if the value of that cell now rises to 1 or more, or decreases to less than zero.

That way you store only the values that are not 0 (**saves memory and allocation considerations**), and you have a theoretically unlimited tape (**more pure implementation**).

```
operation    map
----------------------------
#code_start  <>
+            <0 : 1>
+            <0 : 2>
-            <0 : 1>
-            <>
-            <0 : -1>
>+           <0 : -1, 1 : 1>
<<-          <-1 : -1, 0 : -1, 1 : 1>
```

Maps can be used by including `#include <map>` and created by `std::map<int, int> map_name` or whatever types you want to use.

See documentation here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: Looks interesting, thanks! :)  shame the arduino map function is totally different :/

Comment: You can use array of chars or bytes to save you space (brainfuck anyways prints chars). Just convert the data back and forth. That will bring you 10-15k array on arduino (depending on how carefull you are).